# How to save result of balanced binary tree as an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The below Python program converts a given array elements to a height balanced Binary Search Tree (BST) and prints the traversal of constructed BST. I am wondering how can I save the result as an array.

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def array_to_bst(array_nums):
    if not array_nums:
        return None
    mid_num = len(array_nums)//2
    node = TreeNode(array_nums[mid_num])
    node.left = array_to_bst(array_nums[:mid_num])
    node.right = array_to_bst(array_nums[mid_num+1:])
    return node

def preOrder(node): 
    if not node: 
        return      
    print(node.val)
    preOrder(node.left) 
    preOrder(node.right)   

array_nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

print("Original array:")
print(array_nums)
result = array_to_bst(array_nums)
print("\nArray to a height balanced BST:")
print(preOrder(result))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your `preOrder(node)` function to:

```py
def preOrder(node): 
    if node is None: 
        return []
    print(node.val)
    res = [node.val]
    res += preOrder(node.left) 
    res += preOrder(node.right)
    return res
```

Comment: This function print it as an array. I want to save it as an array and then insert and delete some values from it.

Comment: This function prints the the preOrder traversal **and** returns it as an array. If you do not want to print it, simply remove the print statement. Also, it your code, you have `print(preOrder(result))`, so it will print the returned array if you just copy the code.

Comment: Another quick question, I changed the array_nums to  array_nums = np.random.randint(0,100,10) and it raised with error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()''. Have any idear how to resolve it?

Comment: In the `array_to_bst` function, change the `if` statement to `if len(array_nums) == 0:`